How can I see user 501 processes running on a remote server using `ssh` and `ps -U 501`
I am connecting from an iMac with user name John and ID 501 to my MacMini with the same user name John and ID 501 using ssh.
when I run ps -U 501 remotely I am told there is no user ID 501. If I run that locally the command returns processes owned by 501 as expected. What bit of knowledge am I missing.
 all commands run from ssh session
08:42:09.626 iMac191 ~ 
➜ ssh 169.254.1.1
(john@169.254.1.1) Password:
Last login: Tue Sep 17 14:51:28 2024

john@MacMini ~ % whoami
501

john@MacMini ~ % id
uid=501 gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),704,703,716,702,706,705,701,100(_lpoperator)

john@MacMini ~ % ps -U 501
ps: No ruser name or ID matches '501'

john@MacMini ~ % su john
su: who are you?

john@MacMini ~ % ps -Af | grep 501
  501  2739     1   0 Tue02PM ??         0:00.59 /Applications/DiskWarrior.app/Contents/Helpers/DiskWarriorDaemon
  501 55207 55204   0  8:42AM ??         0:00.61 sshd: john@ttys002 
  501 55898     1   0  8:46AM ??         0:00.59 /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow console
  501 55899     1   0  8:46AM ??         0:01.87 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent
  501 55937     1   0  8:47AM ??         0:03.81 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent
  501 55939     1   0  8:47AM ??         0:00.99 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (Aqua)

john@MacMini ~ % dscacheutil -q user | grep 501

john@MacMini ~ % login root
Password:
Login incorrect
login: login john
Login incorrect


man ps

KEYWORDS
ruid   real user ID 
ruser    user name (from ruid) 
uid    effective user ID 


Looking at the man page:
man ssh


-l login_name.
Specifies the user to log in as on the remote machine.  This also may be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.

So doing this works.
ssh -l <username> [user@]hostname

Creating a configuration file

To configure an ssh configuration file:
cd .ssh


Check if the config file exists:
ls -la


I it doesn't exist create it:
touch config


Now edit the config file:
nano config



The contents of my config file using one space as separator:
Host macmini
HostName 169.254.1.1
User john
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

For Host you can put whatever shorthand you want. In this case I would enter ssh macmini to connect to my macmini at 169.254.1.1 and it would log me in as user "john" using a security key I generated, stored, and configured my server with. You can leave off the last line if you are using macOS Keychain to manage keys (the default).
